# R gtsummary package: How to Manipulate / Hide Rows in Summary Table

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary, tbl

I am working on a project with gtsummary. For one of the tables, I have to build a long table listing covariables before and after the matchit process.

My issue is that for all of the covariables (*Obesity*, for example), it reads one row, *Obesity*, then next row, *Obese*, and then the next, *Not Obese*. That is three tables for which I wish to only show one: *Diabetes N (%)*.

I have tried editing dichotomous variables, introducing `Null`, trying to find a `row_hide` function, but to no avail.

Here is my code:

#### Creation of trial

```r
trialCAS1 <- index_CAS %>%
select(TopDecile, Gender, Obesity, Diabetes, Diabetes_Complex, etc)
```

#### Tbl summary

```r
CAStable1 <- tbl_summary(trialCAS1, 
by = TopDecile,
missing = "no") %>%
add_n() %>%
modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>%
bold_labels()
```

I included the first table I get.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tbl_summary()` function tries its best to guess the type of data passed (categorical, dichotomous, and continuous). It doesn't always guess what we'd like to see, but the default can always be changed using arguments in `tbl_summary()`! I'll use the `trial` data set in the {gtsummary} package as an example.

Here is the default output:

```r
library(gtsummary)
trial %>%
  select(trt, grade, stage) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)
```

[image]

By default, the summary statistics for grade and stage are shown on multiple rows. Imagine, however, we are only interested in the rate of Grade I disease and the rate of Stage T1 cancer.  We can use the `tbl_summary(value=)` argument to specify these are the only values we want displayed (which will then default to print these as dichotomous variables). In the example below, I have also updated the label displayed to indicate these are Grade I and Stage T1 rates only.

```r
trial %>%
  select(trt, grade, stage) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    value = list(grade ~ "I",
                 stage ~ "T1"),
    label = list(grade ~ "Grade I",
                 stage ~ "Stage T1")
  )
```

[image]

Based on what I see from your code and output, I think this code will work for you on your data set:

```r
tbl_summary(
  trialCAS1, 
  by = TopDecile,
  missing = "no".
  value = Obesity ~ "Obese",
  label = Obesity ~ "Obese"
)
```

Comment: Hi Dr. Sjoberg, how does this method of modifying the table apply to tbl_regression? I tried and got an error for an unused argument or other times I tried I received an unusued symbol. I also tried just the label function and it did not work. Please advise.