# How do wee keep only levels of interstes in the output table in tbl_summary?

Tags: gtsummary

I was trying to keep only "Yes" in the out put and keep "No" in the back ground instead of all levels are printed out.

i tried the below code
table4<-Age_group_socio %>%
tbl_summary(by=`Age england`,missing="no",value =list(c(`Cardiac diseases`~'Yes', Hypertension~'Yes',`Liver diseases`~'Yes', `Renal diseases`~'Yes', Diabetes~'Yes', `Neurological diseases`~"Yes", Malignancy~'Yes', Malaria~'Yes', HIV~'Yes', `Other immune deficiency diseases`~'Yes',Tuberculosis~'Yes',`Other chronic lung diseases`~'Yes',Measles~"Yes"  ))) %>%
bold_labels()
Error: 'value' argument must be a list of formulas or named list (see `?syntax`). LHS of the formula is the variable specification, and the RHS is the value specification: list(stage ~ "T1")

Comment: Can you please update your post with a reproducible example (aka a reprex we all can run on our machines)? https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Thanks @Daniel D. Sjoberg . I have solved the problem through the same post in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456616/r-gtsummary-package-how-to-manipulate-hide-rows-in-summary-table